# JPA: Non unique "OneToMany" collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to map a "collection". A collection is a group of items that the user can group as they wish.

```
@Entity 
class Item {
  Long id;
  String name
}

@Entity 
class MyCollection {
  Long id;
  String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  Set<Item> items;
}
```

The user should be able to put `Item` name "foo" into `MyCollection' name "bar" and into 'MyCollection' name "bar2"

The join table that JPA/Hibernate is creating for me, `MyCollection_Item` has has 4 indexes, the PK (`MyCollection_id, Item_id`), a unique index (`Item_id`), and the 2 foreign keys.

I do not want it to create the unique index on `Item_id`. This prevents me from having:

`MyCollection_id, Item_Id`

`1, 1`

`1, 2`

`2, 1`

I am sure this type of mapping must be possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneToMany is when you want to map **one** object to **many** objects

ManyToMany is when you want to map **many** object to **many** objects (like you try to do here)

Answer (score 0):

You need a ManyToMany but you have it mapped as a OneToMany.